# Prevent repeating and writing shorter

Tags: javascript

I check three elements for their availability. If they are defined, I do the same actions for each element. I would like to avoid the code being repeated. How can I write this in a shorter, more efficient way?

```js
const studentElem = component.find("students").getElement();
if (studentElem != undefined) {
   let studentNoice = studentElem.innerText;
   studentNoice = studentNoice.replace('classNo', 'Reg No.');
   studentElem.innerHTML = studentNoice;
}
const staffElem = component.find("staff").getElement();
if (staffElem != undefined) {
   let staffNoice = staffElem.innerText;
   staffNoice = staffNoice.replace('staffNo', 'Staff Rec.');
   staffElem.innerHTML = staffNoice;
}
const parentElem = component.find("parents").getElement();
if (parentElem != undefined) {
   let parentNoice = parentElem.innerText;
   parentNoice = parentNoice.replace('ParentID', 'P-ID.');
   parentElem.innerHTML = parentNoice;
}
```

Comment: Security warning: you should assign `innerText`, not `innerHTML`.  Otherwise the text content could be turned into executable script.

Comment: @user2740650 Better yet, use `.textContent` instead of `innerText` as it is more standard and works slightly differently.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you! Can `.textContent` be used same way as the innerText? what do you mean by "works slightly differently" ?

Comment: You use `.textContent` as you would `.innerText`, but `innerText` (although supported everywhere) is only a standard in the WHATWG HTML 5 standard, not the W3C Standard (like `.textContent` is), so IMO, it's better to use the W3C standard. You can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText) about the differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, this should be condensed. You can do this by passing the variable data into a function as arguments and making decisions based on those argument values.

You also don't need to explicitly check for `!=undefinded`. You can just check for the existence of the element `if(elem)`. And, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> It is recommended that you do not use innerHTML when inserting plain
> text; instead, use Node.textContent. This doesn't parse the passed
> content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw text.

```
function foo(role, find, replace){
  const elem = component.find(role).getElement();
  // No need to check for !=undefined because that essentially means
  // you are checking for a "truthy" value, which is what an if condition
  // checks for by default, so checking the variable itself forces the 
  // value to be converted to a Boolean. If the element exists, the Boolean
  // becomes true and if not, it is false.
  if (elem) {
    // Setting up variables that are only used once is a bit of a waste
    // Just do the work here and there's less code to write and maintain
    elem.textContent = elem.textContent.replace(find, replace);
  }
}

// You then call the function and pass the variable data
foo("students", 'classNo', 'Reg No.');
foo("staff", 'staffNo', 'Staff Rec.');
foo("parents", 'ParentID', 'P-ID.');
```

Comment: Beautiful and very informative!! Just wondering instead of calling the function 3 times can this be done using like a `forEach`?

Comment: @Fergoso I was only demonstrating the syntax for invoking the function. I have no idea how often the function will need to be called, so I really can't say if it would be better to call it in a loop. If you were going to use `.forEach()` you'd need an array to call it on and we haven't been given enough information know if that's realistic.

Comment: Cool! :) thank you. this will be called only once at the time the page is loaded.

Comment: @Fergoso You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make a function!

```js
function yourBuisnessLogic(componentName, subStr, newSubStr){
    const elem = component.find(componentName).getElement();
    if (elem != undefined) {
       let notice = elem.innerText;
       notice = notice.replace(subStr, newSubStr);
       elem.innerHTML = notice;
    }
}
```

and function calls :

```
yourBuisnessLogic("students",'classNo', 'Reg No.');
yourBuisnessLogic("staff",'staffNo', 'Staff Rec.');
yourBuisnessLogic("parents",'ParentID', 'P-ID.');
```